# How to set text property on keyDownHandler on TextInput in Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, text, textinput

Simple and straight forward.
I extended a mx.controls.TextInput to create a custom component with a different behavior.
I'm trying to set the **text** property on the keyDownHandler(), and for some reason it doesn't work as I expected. The text on the component just kinda ignore the change.
I'm using Flex 3.6.
Down here is a simple example code that explains what's going on:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" xmlns:customcomponent="com.test.customcomponent.*">
    <customcomponent:TextTest x="20" y="20"/>   
</mx:Application>
```

And below de AS class:

```
package com.test.customcomponent
{
    import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

    import mx.controls.TextInput;

    public class TextTest extends TextInput
    {
        public function TextTest()
        {
            super();
        }

        override protected function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
            text = "lol. It doesn't work";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent the default key down event.

```
    override protected function keyDownHandler(event:KeyboardEvent):void{
        text = "lol. It doesn't work";
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        event.stopPropagation()
    }
```

Comment: Tried that, didn't work..
For some reason, whenever I press CTRL, SHIFT or TAB key it works properly...

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to prevent the default handling, you have to have a high enough priority on your handler (which keyDownHandler() does not have). This means you need to register your own method with priority > 0.

You can try like this:

```
public function MyTextInput() {
    addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, yourHandler, 
                     false, EventPriority.BINDING, true);
    ...
}

private function yourHandler(event : KeyboardEvent) : void {
    // stop further handling
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    event.stopPropagation();  

    // do your work here
    text = ...;
}
```